# FluentValidator. Add _validateService for all models

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I need to creat fluent _validator where I will not use only one model. If I need more models in my controller? I will create for each model _validator{modelName}?

My code

```
public class UserDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<UserDTO>
{
    public UserDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress()
            .WithMessage("{PropertyName} should be not empty.");
        RuleFor(p => p.Password).NotNull().Length(5, 30)
            .WithMessage("{PropertyName} should be not empty.");
        RuleFor(p => p.PasswordConfirm).Equal(p => p.Password);
    }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
 private readonly IValidator<UserDTO> _validator;

    public UserController(IValidator<UserDTO> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }
```

HttpPost

```
 var validResult = _validator.Validate(model);
 if (validResult.IsValid)
 {

 }
```

Startup

```
 services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation();
 services.AddSingleton<IValidator<UserDTO>, UserDtoValidator>();
```

It is work good. But I need multiple models in my _validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it makes much sense to make fluent validator universal, because all models may have different attributes and require different validations to validate attributes.

Unless these models of yours inherit a common class, then you can use a BaseValidator to share a validator method.

```
 public class Teacher 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserDTO  
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
    }
   public class BaseValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> 
    {
        public BaseValidator()
        {
        }
    }

    public class TeacherValidator : BaseValidator<Teacher>
    {
        public TeacherValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(p => p.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} should be not empty.");
            RuleFor(p => p.Age).InclusiveBetween(18, 60)
                .WithMessage("{PropertyName} should between 18-60.");
            RuleFor(p => p.Gender).Must(x => new string[] { "Male", "Female" }.Contains(x)).WithMessage("Then gender can only be male or female");
        }
    }
    public class UserDtoValidator : BaseValidator<UserDTO>
    {
        public UserDtoValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(p => p.Email).NotEmpty().EmailAddress()
                .WithMessage("{PropertyName} should be not empty.");
            RuleFor(p => p.Password).NotNull().Length(5, 30)
                .WithMessage("{PropertyName} should be not empty.");
            RuleFor(p => p.PasswordConfirm).Equal(p => p.Password);
        }
    }
```

Or you can have a look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49109273/12884742).